# Where to get the eligible library tag file in Android O

Tags: android-source

In https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/deftool, it mentions that Google provides a tag file to classify the framework shared libraries, including LL-NDK, SP-NDK, VNDK, VNDK-SP and etc. However, after searching on this website and googling it, I'm not able to find the tag file. Where does Google provide it?

Thanks
Jincan

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get such files.
You must get the file of vendor.img and system.img, for that is a file for deploying at "vendor partition" and "system partition" at a device.

## Step 1

Please visit to [Driver Binaries for Nexus and Pixel Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/images).
There are images for two devices.

```
taimen  (Pixel 2 XL) 
walleye (Pixel 2)
```

## Step 2: Method for file expand

Please read [README.md](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/vndk/tools/definition-tool/README.md).
There is undermentioned code

```
$ simg2img system.img system.raw.img

$ simg2img vendor.img vendor.raw.img

$ mkdir system

$ mkdir vendor

$ sudo mount -o loop,ro system.raw.img system

$ sudo mount -o loop,ro vendor.raw.img vendor

$ sudo python3 vndk_definition_tool.py vndk \
    --system system \
    --vendor vendor \
    --aosp-system /path/to/aosp/generic/system \
    --tag-file eligible-list-v3.0.csv
```

For detail, Please see that "README.md".

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development
~/tools/development/vndk/tools/definition-tool/datasets[master]$ ls
eligible-list-o-mr1-release.csv  eligible-list-o-release.csv  minimum_dlopen_deps.txt  minimum_tag_file.csv
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!